# npm is putting all dependencies and sub-dependecies int he same folder

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, npm

I have a package.json file with about 20 dependencies in my project. When I do

```
npm install
```

it places all the dependencies and sub-dependencies in the top most node_modules directory. It contains hundreds of modules when it should only be my 20. The sub-dependencies should be in the node_module directories under my main dependencies but it has created a flat structure.

I'm using npm 3.5.4 and node 0.10.41 on Ubuntu 14.04

Can any one assist me in getting the modules to install like they should with the correct tree structure?

EDIT-----
Adding my packages.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "lms",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aliasify": "^1.8.0",
    "angular": "^1.4.7",
    "angular-animate": "^1.4.7",
    "angular-aria": "^1.4.7",
    "angular-material": "^0.11.4",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.7",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.15",
    "angular-ui-sortable": "^0.13.4",
    "backbone": "^1.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "browser-sync": "^2.9.12",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "browserify-ngannotate": "^1.0.1",
    "del": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint": "^1.8.0",
    "eslint-config-defaults": "^7.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-connect-php": "0.0.7",
    "gulp-eslint": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-open": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.4.2",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "ng-backbone": "file:local_node_modules/ng-backbone",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "aliasify"
    ]
  },
  "aliasify": {
    "aliases": {
      "underscore": "lodash"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your program still work?

Comment: @Manu, Yes, the program still works. But dealling with hundreds on files in one directory is unwieldy; makes it difficult to find stuff when reading through code.

Comment: can you show us your `package.json` ?!

Comment: @marcel, addedd the contents of the packages.json file.

Comment: BTW--I develope on two computers. I installed all the packages successfully once with out problems--don't know what the deal is now.

Comment: I thought NPM did this as an optimization - it can help especially when multiple modules share dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behaviour. Since version 3 `npm` tries to de-duplicate dependencies and use a flat tree whereever possible.

See https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3

Comment: Thanks! I searched for hours for something that would explain this behavior.